# Does this vector set span $\Bbb{R}^3$?

Tags: linear-algebra

> Determine whether $S = \Big\{(1, 0, −1),(2, 1, 0),(0, 1, 1)\Big\}$ spans $\Bbb{R}^3$.

So I'm going to let $(u_1, u_2, u_3)$ be a random vector.

$$(u_1, u_2, u_3) = c_1(1,0,-1) + c_2(2,1,0) + c_3(0,1,1)
  \\ \hspace{0.5cm}= (c_1 + 2c_2, c_2 + c_3, -c_1 + c_3) $$

So it leads to the equations:

$$c_1 + 2c_2 = u_1$$
$$c_2 + c_3  = u_2$$
$$-c_1 + c_3 = u_3$$

$\Rightarrow$

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}
\sim \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 2 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

I know one way to check this: the determinant of this matrix is found by taking the determinant of the first column:

$$1 * 1 * -1 = -1$$

So the matrix has a unique solution so any vector in $\Bbb{R}^3$ can be written with those 3 vectors so these vectors span $\Bbb{R}^3$

Is this right?

Comment: Yes, this is correct.  You used quite a few more words than I would have in constructing the matrix., the columns are merely the vectors in question.

Comment: The "determinant of the first column" does not exist.

Comment: Can I not find the determinant in this way @amsmath?

Comment: @JMoravitz what words are redundant?

Comment: Well, at least I did not understand what you did there.

Comment: I had assumed that the OP meant continuing with the row reduction process and multiplying along the diagonal which does indeed give $1\cdot 1\cdot (-1)$ for the determinant.  The specific method used to find the determinant could certainly be made clearer though, I agree.

Comment: I did what was called (I think) coefficient expansion but using the first column. Essentially I did 1 * (minor of $a_{11}$) + 0 * (minor of $a_{21}$ + 0 * (minor of $a_{31}$

Comment: I would begin as: "We want to check if $(1,0,-1),(2,1,0),(0,1,1)$ act as a basis for $\Bbb R^3$.  To do this, we can consider the determinant of the matrix $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}1&2&0\\0&1&1\\-1&0&1\end{smallmatrix}\right]$..."  Most of your beginning after introducing the problem and before introducing the matrix can be omitted.

Comment: @Jwan622 This is correct but it can (of course) not be seen from what you did. Just write "The determinant is $1\cdot|\begin{smallmatrix}1 & 1\\2 & 1\end{smallmatrix}| = 1-2 = -1$."

Answer (score 1):

Yes in that case the derivation by the determinant is the straightforward method.

As an alternative, particularly useful for larger matrices, we can use RREF

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\to 
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 2 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\to
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 \end{bmatrix}
$$

and note that since we have three pivots the given set is a linearly independent set of vectors.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your solution is perfect. The determinant trick does it.

The other way to do it is to show that the vectors are linearly independent which again boils down to determinant being non-zero.